# Forms in Tab control

Tags: .net, vb.net

IDE: VB.NET (2008)

I have an mdi form in my program. As usual this mdi form acts like a container to several child forms. However, I need to implement a tabbed system so that my forms rather than appearing in mdi form should appear in a tab page.

So I inserted a tab control on my mdi form and when a form is added I say TabPage1.Controls.Add(Form). It seems to be working okay until I found out that now my form is like a control so methods like Me.GetActiveMDIChild etc won't work.

Is there any I can solve two problems :

- Generally when a particular child form is selected we can know when we see the titlebar. In this case because forms are added as controls there is no difference in the titlebar of a selected or non selected form. Is there a way to fix this ?
- Can I determine which form is selected. Something like Me.ActiveMdiChild. I can go through control collection of a tab page to get a list of forms but figuring out which form is selected is something I don't know.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Cheers,
GR

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I would use `TabPage1.Controls.Add(Form)`.
Instead you can show/hide forms when the user activates tabs.
One implementation in c# can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TabbedMDIChildForms.aspx).

I prefer to use 3rd party controls for this, like the ones from Infragistics or Telerik.

Comment: I think if I can figure out which form is active then I could manage. There is something like ActiveControl in vb.net. But I dunno how I can use it to determine which form is currently selected.

Comment: You could use `Me.ActiveMDIChild`?!

Comment: Me.ActiveMDIChild will not work if my form is inside a tab control.

Comment: Did you look at the example I referred to in my answer? You don't put the forms in a tab control. You dock the tab control on the top of the MDI form and open the forms outside the tab control.

Comment: You are right Ole_Brun. That what I have done now. My tab is docked at bottom and I show/hide forms depending on the tab selected. It is working okay. There are only two problems. A bit of flicker as forms are shown if user selects a different tab and location of forms change if I hide them & show.

Comment: sounds good! About the form location, I guess you can handle this in code. Or you could always show them maximized within the parent.

Comment: Regarding location I maybe able to handle it in the code but showing forms if tab changes is a bit slow. User can see the form being shown. How can I take care of this ?

Comment: Not sure why this is slow. Showing/hiding forms is usually quick. If you are going to use this in production, I would seriously considered using a 3rd party control for this. Then you will also get a lot of other features.

Comment: Third party controls makes things slower. I have used telerik in the past before. I am myself wondering why its slow.?